# When are UITabBarController's views loaded?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs each with their own `UIViewController` file. In the Tabbar's `viewDidLoad()` when I iterate through the children views in a loop, each view appears to be there:

```
if let childViewControllers = self.viewControllers {
    for viewController in childViewControllers {
       print("Hi")                               // Prints "Hi" 3 times
    }
}
```

However, if I put a print statement inside the individual childrens `UIViewController` file's `viewDidLoad()` only the first child's print statement is executed (The first tab of the tabbar).

How is it that the `viewDidLoad()` of the other children aren't executed yet I'm still able to iterate through all the tabbar's children and do things such as setting their properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view of each tab is loaded only when needed, meaning only when you click on the tab to view it. Only the first tab prints your statement because it is the one that you are viewing. Try to click on the other tabs and you'll see the statement being printed as well.